# DataLabelSettings builder not working Appropriately in syncfusion bar chart

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

I'm using the Syncfusion package in my App I am trying to display different values for chart labels from the actual chart value
so if I'm using the builder in DataLabelSettings the data is not displayed Appropriately
[image]

how data looks if a leave it as default

[image]

how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reported issue regarding the data label template is not positioned properly has been fixed and included in our weekly patch release. To avoid this issue please update your chart package to the below version.

Version: https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_charts/versions/20.4.50